# can't access bios solid motherboard beep

Tags: windows-8, laptop, boot, motherboard, bios

You can skip this part if you just want to get to the point.                goto :question

I have a toshiba satellite c885, that originally had windows 8 installed.  I deleted windows 8, and installed ubuntu.  On my computer, since it came from the manufacturer with windows 8, I have to enter bios (with <kbd>F2</kbd> at startup) and change eufi boot mode to csm in order to boot anything but windows.  Now I want to install windows again.  To do so, I loaded a windows 8 iso onto a flash drive, and went to boot it.  Unfortunately, I enabled a mode called "fast boot" under the boot speed section in bios.  I also was in CSM mode.  In order to boot my flash drive, I have to be in EUFI boot mode.  But with this fast boot mode, I can't access bios for some reason.

If I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, then power on my computer, the motherboard starts beeping.  I know a motherboard beep is some sort of error message, but past there, I don't know.  It was a solid beep, not a series of beeps, just one long beep that continues until I press the power key.  This would happen whenever I would try to enter the bios while in CSM mode.  How I would overcome this:  I would power on my computer, immediately press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, the screen would go black, and the system would basicly reboot, which then for some reason I could press <kbd>F2</kbd> and get to bios just fine, to change back to EUFI.

But now with this fast boot, that isn't working.  I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>, the screen would go black, then power back on, but now none of the bios keys are doing anything.  Nothing.

What I have done:
I have reseated the CMOS battery (taken it out, and put it right back in).
This had no effect whatsoever.

I have taken out my hard drive, and then powered on my computer.  It goes to some screen saying no bootable devices, press any key to retry.  It doesn't recognize my usb (it is set to boot second, I think) since it is in csm mode.

```
:question
```

I just need a way to reset all bios settings.  I used to be able to do this from within bios with <kbd>F9</kbd>.

With the CMOS thing, do I need to let the battery sit out for a period of time?  I took out the main computer battery because I didn't want to chance something frying or getting shocked.  Do I have do drain the CMOS battery?  Should I short the circuit?

Whatever advice you give me, please be thourogh, as today was the first time I ever opened a computer :D

Comment: How long did you remove the CMOS battery for? A quick in-out isn't sufficient. Leave it out for a few minutes.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Thank you for the reply.  I left it out for a half hour, and it told me the battery was low, press f2 to change time and date!  Thank you so much, as I can now access bios again!

Comment: If the CMOS battery is reporting a low voltage I would suggest getting a replacement. It should only cost a couple dollars from any electronics store.

Answer (score 3):

To reset BIOS to default settings on a Toshiba Satellite, do the following

**Information**

This bulletin documents the several different methods for gaining access to the BIOS Setup feature of most models of Toshiba computers. These setting are stored in non-volatile CMOS memory, hence the alternative term "CMOS Setup". The settings are managed by a utility program built into the computer's BIOS (Basic Input/Output System).

For Toshiba notebook PCs manufactured since the introduction of Windows XP
One or more of the following methods will be effective:

**F2 key method**

Turn the computer on. If you see an invitation to press the F2 key to enter Setup, do so. The Setup screen will appear.

**Toshiba Hardware utility method**

Run the Toshiba Hardware utility from the Toshiba Console. It may also accessible (as 'HWSetup') from the Windows Control Panel. Changes to some of the settings will require re-starting the computer. This method is the only way to access the BIOS settings on some notebook PCs (Satellite 5000 series, for example). (For these machines, pressing and holding the F12 key immediately after powering-on the notebook will allow you to alter the notebook's boot priority.)

If the Toshiba Hardware utility is not present, try the F2 key method and the Esc key method (see below). The Toshiba Hardware utility may be downloaded from the Toshiba support website at http://support.toshiba.com

If the computer is fully off, and/or to avoid having to re-start it (and Windows), use one or the other of the following two methods. The PC will have to be truly off (not suspended, or in standby mode, or in hibernation mode). If an external keyboard is attached to the notebook (either directly or via a docking station or a port-replicator), disconnect it until you have completed this procedure.

**Esc key method**

Turn the computer on. If you do not see a prompt to press the F2 key, then immediately press and hold the Esc key for three seconds, and then release it. When prompted to, press the F1 key. The Setup screen will appear.

**For Toshiba notebook PCs manufactured before the introduction of Windows XP**
One or more of the following methods are appropriate:

**HWSetup method**

Run the HWSetup utility from the Windows Control Panel. This utility provides a relatively user-friendly way to change the BIOS settings. Changes to some of the settings will require re-starting the PC (and Windows). HWSetup was pre-installed on all but early Toshiba notebook models. If it doesn't appear as a Control Panel applet on your computer, you may be able to download it from the Toshiba Support website as part of the Toshiba Utilities package for your model.

**Esc key method**

If an external keyboard is attached to the notebook, either directly or via a docking station or a port-replicator, disconnect it. Turn the computer on. Immediately press and hold the Esc key for three seconds, and then release it. When prompted to, press the F1 key. The Setup screen will appear. The PC will have to be truly off (not suspended, or in standby mode, or in hibernation mode) for this method to work.

**TSETUP method**

Run the TSETUP utility, under MS-DOS. TSETUP runs correctly only when executed from a 'native' MS-DOS prompt, and with the processor running in real mode -- so not from a Windows 'DOS box', and without any memory manager software running (EMM386.EXE, HIMEM.SYS, or QEMM386.EXE, for example). TSetup was pre-installed on most early Toshiba notebook models (except for the very earliest models). It is available from the Toshiba Support website.

**For Toshiba desktop PCs and servers**

Press and hold the F2 key immediately after turning the computer on (during the Power-on Self Test (POST)).

See [Toshiba BIOS Reset KB Article](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?soid=627009) for original post.

Comment: I don't need someone to tell me how to enter bios.  I have done that a great many times.  one of the comments answered my question.

Comment: @coltonon, if you read the whole answer it gives you a way to access the BIOS Settings if the option for F2 doesn't work or is not visible.

Comment: you are welcome, I also upvoted it as well